# Extract list of words from PDF in Python

Tags: python, list, pdf, text

I am trying to extract the words of a PDF in the form of a list.

I can extract text from PDF but I am not able to put that in a list

```
import PyPDF2
import pandas as pd
PDFfilename = '1200.pdf' 

pdfFileObj = open(PDFfilename, 'rb') 

pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj) 

for i in range(1, pdfReader.numPages):
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i) 
    print('\n\n')
    txt=pageObj.extractText();
    print(txt)
pdfFileObj.close()
```

Expected result : [Alabama, Building, ..]
Actual Result : Alabama Building

Answer (score 0):

If your result looks like this --- 
Alabama Building Something Happened In There

```
txt = txt.split( )
print txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split() method for this. Like:

```
txt=pageObj.extractText().split()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do more with your text, you can also tokenize it. For handling this, I'd recommend [SpaCy](https://spacy.io/).

First, install it and add SpaCy's "small" model in the English language

```bash
pip install spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Then, add these three lines to your code.

```python
import spacy # with other imports
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm") # early in your script to load the model
doc = nlp(txt) # before your print(txt) line
```

`doc` will be iterable. And you'll be able to analyse each word with part of speech tagging, for example.

```python
for token in doc:
  print(token, token.pos_)
```

Output:

```py
Alabama PROPN # 'PROPN' means proper noun
Building NOUN
```

Have fun :)

Comment: I tried this, its giving this error with spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")- OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

Comment: Then I tried this in terminal     python -m spacy download en  ; I got -> Download successful but linking failed
Creating a shortcut link for 'en' didn't work (maybe you don't have admin
permissions?), but you can still load the model via its full package name: nlp =
spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

Comment: Please read my reply carefully... I wrote ```python -m spacy download **en_core_web_sm**```